# How to create a New column variable with the data from all other columns using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am working on a Data set, and want to create a new variable column with all the columns which are present in data set:

[image]

I want to make a new variable from `CODE` with all the related rows to same number (8480-6 and 8462-4)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Plus, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, `nlp`, or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import pandas as pd 


     data = pd.DataFrame(
                  {'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011','13/2/2011'], 
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theater', 'Comedy'], 
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]}) 


     data['Discounted_Price'] = data['Cost'] - (0.1 * data['Cost']) 


    print(data)
```

Add discount column to the data frame I think this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the indexing from pandas which is good described [here](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/#loc-selection)

Therefore try:

```
# select the data
sel = data.loc[data['code'] == XX]
# write the data out
data['new_col'] = sel
```

**Edit:** Filter Option

You can slice the dataframe with conditions and select needed the columns

```
data[data['CODE'] == '8480-6'][['col_1','col_2']]
```

Comment: Hello Rene, Thank you very much for the reply. I am looking to make 2 new columns from a column called CODE from above table. I want data from other columns also be shared accordingly to whichever row I want to set in different columns. Example: for code 8480-6, I want related measure ID, NPI, date of Service etc. and for 8462-4 Code I want that related measure ID, NPI, Date of service etc

Comment: Should the information be concatenated the new column or do you just need a filter?

Comment: Hello Rene, I need a Filter